# Laravel Load Pdf in Dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

The report that I generate needs `Bookman Old Style` font. However it does not reflect in the pdf. If I just view it as an HTML, it displays the text in 'Bookman Olds Style'

```
function print_ta()
{
    //return view('calendaractivities.calendar_activities.generate_ta');

    // Create a new instance of Dompdf
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();


    // Set options for Dompdf
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
    $dompdf->setOptions($options);

    // Render the view file and convert it to HTML
    $html = view('calendaractivities.calendar_activities.generate_ta')->render();

    // Load the HTML into Dompdf
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

    // Render the PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // Output the generated PDF to the browser
    $dompdf->stream('document.pdf', ['Attachment' => false]);
}
```

And here is my HTML code. This page has Header in the First page only and hase Footer in every page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>

      <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Header & Footer test</title>

<style>
    @page {
        margin: 10mm;
    }

    body {
        line-height: 1.3;
        /* Avoid fixed header and footer to overlap page content */
        margin-top: 10px;
        /* Adjust this value as needed */
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .first-page #header {
        position: fixed;
        top: -105px;
        left: -90px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        /* For testing */
    }

    .other-pages #header {
        display: none;
    }

    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: -90px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        font-size: 6pt;
        color: #777;
        /* For testing */
        background: red;
    }

    /* Print progressive page numbers */
    .page-number:before {
        /* counter-increment: page; */
        content: "Pagina "counter(page);
    }

    /* table css 1 px solid black and collapse all borders */
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    /* add border to tr th and td */
    table tr th,
    table tr td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .th_header {
        height: 2cm;
        font-size: 16.66px;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-family: "Bookman Old Style", serif !important;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="first-page">
    <header id="header">
        
        <img src="{{ url('images/header_image.png') }}" width="123%" height="130%">
    </header>
</div>

<div class="other-pages">
    <header id="header">
        {{-- add an empty header for other pages --}}
    </header>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
    <img src="{{ url('images/footer_image.png') }}" width="123%">
</footer>

<div id="content">
    <br>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th class="th_header" colspan="4">
                AUTHORITY TO TRAVEL</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where do you specify the file path of the font containing the font type? Does it work in HTML for you only because this font is already stored on your computer? In every case, you need to provide the file path for the font stored on your website! (`@font-face`, `src`, `url()`)

Comment: If you have declared the font (assigned a name to the file path of the font) in the CSS of your current file using `@font-face`, it is advisable to provide appropriate permissions to the folder containing the fonts. For example, if you store them in the `storage/app/public/fonts` folder, which is symbolically accessible from the `public` directory as `storage/fonts`, you can set the permissions using the command `sudo chmod -R 755 storage/fonts`.

Comment: [What is @font-face?](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.php) | [Dompdf Custom Font Loading - Issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2773#issuecomment-1040562521)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to include custom font to HTML

We can always specify the font type for HTML code using CSS. In the case of a custom font type, there must always be a file containing the font type, to which you can assign a name in CSS that you will refer to later when specifying the font-family.

###### Example for Declare MyCustomFont

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: MyCustomFont;
  src: url(http://mydomainname.com/storage/fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

###### Example for Using MyCustomFont

```css
.classname {
  font-family: MyCustomFont;
}
```

[What is @font-face?](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.php)

#### Enable custom Font using on DOMPDF

```php
$options = $dompdf->getOptions();

// It enables all file type of fonts using
$options->set('defaultMediaType', 'all');

// It enables font subsetting, which means that only the characters you actually use will be included in the generated PDF
$options->set('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true);
```

#### Set Folder of Fonts on DOMPDF

If your fonts stored on `storage/app/public/fonts` folder, what can call from `public` as `storage/fonts` by symbolic link.

```php
$options = $dompdf->getOptions();
$options->setFontCache(storage_path('fonts'));
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$options->set('pdfBackend', 'CPDF');
$options->setChroot([
  'resources/views/',
  storage_path('fonts'),
]);
```

[Dompdf Custom Font Loading - Issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2773#issuecomment-1040562521)

#### WOFF or TTF using better to PDF?

I am attaching [@K J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j)'s excellent insight on the supported font formats used in PDF.

> I encourage older PDF.TTF fonts not modern HTML.WOFF as many variants of woff will not be acceptable for older PDF usage where only TTF was acceptable as an alternative for imbedding

Comment: if i try to jsut return the view as html, it works correctly. But using dompdf the font not working anymore. 

`<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: "MyCustomFont";
        src: url("{{ url('storage/fonts/bookman.ttf') }}") format("truetype");
    }

    .classname {
        font-family: MyCustomFont;
    }
</style>



<p class="classname">TESTING BOOKMAN</p>
`
the view page is 'calendaractivities.calendar_activities.generate_ta`

Comment: and the font is stored in `app\storage\app\public\fonts`

Comment: try add static url to font-face, for example: `http://example.com/storage/fonts/bookman.ttf`

Comment: if use inline <style> then can use `public_path()` by Laravel: `src: url({{ public_path("storage/fonts/bookman.ttf") }})`

Comment: i tried `url("ro.test/storage/fonts/bookman.ttf') }}') format('truetype")`. At first it work but after next refresh it didnt. Maybe sometimes it loaded sometimes not.

Comment: is there a way on how to check if the font was really loaded?

Comment: If you call the static URL of the TTF file, will the font load for you? If not, then the issue lies with the file not being available online.

Comment: Maybe try to set `'defaultMediaType', 'all'` and `'isFontSubsettingEnabled', true` options. However, I suppose you have already tried this.